# reducing the number of sql queries from the front

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-blade, eloquent-relationship

```
    orders
        id - integer
        client_id - integer
     
    clients
        id - integer
        name - string
     
    accounts
        id - integer
        client_id - integer
        amount - integer
```

##### Controller

```
$orders = Order::with(['transaction', 'client', 'delivery', 'address'])
  ->latest()->paginate(50);
return view('admin.order.index', compact('orders'));
```

##### FrontEnd

```
      <td class="text-center">
        <strong>{{$item->client->invoice}}</strong>
      </td>
```

##### Client Model

```
  public function getInvoiceAttribute()
  {
    return $this->account()->sum('amount');
  }
```

[image]

I don't know how to use [Has Many Through](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqccE0lSOjs&t=421s).
Or how to solve this situation
I don't need an account at the front but I need sum of amounts

Comment: eager loading may can help you https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I did so

##### added invoice column to write sum of account->amounts

```
Schema::table('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->integer('invoice')->default(0);
        });
```

##### after than added AccountObserver

```
class AccountObserver
{
  public function creating(Account $account)
  {
    $account->client()->increment('invoice',$account->amount);
  }

  public function updating(Account $account)
  {
    $account->client()->increment('invoice',$account->amount);
  }
}
```

##### Controller

```
$orders = Order::with(['transaction', 'client', 'delivery', 'address'])
  ->latest()->paginate(50);
return view('admin.order.index', compact('orders'));
```

###### View

```
<td class="text-center">
    <strong >{{$item->client->invoice}}</strong>
</td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```php
$this->account()->sum('amount');
```

This creates a SQL query. If you call it in a foreach loop, it will do N Queries.

You could eager load the sum.

```php
$orders = Order::query()
    ->with([
        'transaction',
        'client' => fn ($client) => $client->withSum('accounts as invoice', 'amount'), // or function ($client) { $client->withSum('accounts as invoice', 'amount'); }, 
        'delivery',
        'address'
    ])
    ->latest()
    ->paginate(50);

return view('admin.order.index', compact('orders'));
```

```xml
@foreach ($orders as $item)
  ...
  <td class="text-center">
    <strong>{{ $item->client->invoice }}</strong>
  </td>
  ...
@endforeach
```

Remove the `getInvoiceAttribute` method from the `Client` Model

Comment: Thanks. but after that the count of queries 111 became

Comment: Which is 50 less than before. 1 query per row on a 50 row table.  Maybe there's another part of your view that is creating queries. Can you share everything inside your foreach loop?